# How can you recognize sign language in a mobile application?

Tags: iphone, android

Is it possible to recognize sign language (like American Sign Language, ASL) in an iPhone or Android application?

Are there libraries that are available to do this?  If not, how would you suggest I get started in writing an application that could recognize sign language?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible with the video camera. However, I am not aware of an existing code base that supports this.  You could look into OpenCV.  It is available for both iPhone and android.

Comment: ohh! i see., your right..there are only few who share their codes hmmm, regarding in opencv i find it confusing porting opencv in android platform..but still working on it.